Syntactically, who does Jesus refer to as 'to you' and 'those outside' in Mark 4:11?
Contextually, is 'to you' restricted to the disciples present, and does 'those outside' refer to those not chosen as disciples, or those rejecting Jesus?
Text: (NET)

He said to them, "The secret of the kingdom of God has been given to
you. But to those outside, everything is in parables,


Jesus is addressing His disciples and explaining the purpose of His parables therefore:
Syntactically:

“To you”: refers to the disciples and those around who were present with Jesus as they are the ones to whom the “secret of the kingdom of God”
has been given.


And when he was alone, those around him with the twelve asked him
about the parables. (Mark 4:10)


“Those outside”: refers to people who are not part of the
inner circle of Jesus. Including those who are not chosen as disciples and those rejecting Jesus.


but unto them that are without; "to strangers", as the Syriac and Arabic versions render it, who were not the disciples of Christ, nor admitted to any intimacy with him; who came only to amuse themselves
with the sight of his person and miracles: (Gill's Exposition)

Jesus revealed the mysteries of the kingdom of God to those who were spiritually receptive, while concealing these truths from those who were not open to them.

All who hear His words, but do not seek their deeper meaning, are spiritually ‘outside', just as His mother and brothers were ‘outside'
earlier, so that they were not welcomed as His ‘brother, sister and
mother' (Mark 3:31). (Peter Pett's Commentary on the Bible)


Jesus' instruction in Mark 4:11 essentially divides all people into two groups:

His disciples to whom is revealed the mysteries of the kingdom of God - this is the "you" He is addressing
everyone else.

However, and this is important, Jesus' final instruction as recorded in matt 28:19 is for His disciples to make disciples of "all nations" - this is presumably done by explaining the mystery of the kingdom of God and then baptizing such people as want to know these things and accept them by faith.

Of note also is what Jesus said near the start of his ministry and addressed to those with faith in God as their heavenly Father, "But seek ye first the kingdom of God, and his righteousness, and all these things shall be added unto you." Mat.6:33. The mystery of the Kingdom and of God's righteousness is utterly bound up with his righteousness displayed at Golgotha; truly an immense mystery, now revealed.
